# Android Keys in AndroidKeyStore without encryption

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore, key-pair

It is possible to store key pairs unencrypted by omitting [KeyPairGeneratorSpec.setEncryptionRequired()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html#setEncryptionRequired()). In this case, the key pair is presumably stored in clear, rather than encrypted with a key derived from the device lock screen credentials.

It is also known that hardware-backed keys are not in fact stored in the TEE, but rather, in /data/misc/keystore/user_0.

If keys are stored in clear, wouldn't a root user with full access to the file system then be able to extract the private key material?